# C++ Loading DLL Error

Tags: c++, opengl, java, dll

So I'm attempting to fix a OpenGL in Java problem by making a DLL in C++ and then call it from Java but I've ran into an issue. So I'm testing a basic DLL in C++ and I got this error: "error: 'hGetProcDLL' was not declared in this scope|" This is my code:

```
#include<windows.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef void (*f_print)(string);

    int main()
    {
    //The DLL Is Called OpenGL But I'm Making A Basic Print Function In It To Test It
    HINSTANCE DLLI = LoadLibrary("C:\\OpenGL.dll");
    if (DLLI == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Error loading DLL" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    f_print print = (f_print)GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL, "print");
    if (!print)
    {
        cout << "Invalid function!" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    print("FUNCTION!!!!!!!!!");;
    return 0;
}
```

Any idea what's happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s just that you call your variable `DLLI` then try to use it as `hGetProcIDDLL`.

Comment: That's not the problem!

Comment: ohhhhh sorry thats the problem!!!!!